# Regex backreference not working

Tags: c++, regex, tags, backreference

I want to match this html-like pattern: `<12>Some content with \n in it<12>`

Important is that only complete items are marked (numbers MUST match), means when one tag is missing the content should not be marked.  `<12>Some content with \n in it<13>test<13>`

This is what I've got so far:

```
(<\s*[0-9]+\>)(.*?[^<]*?)(<\s*[0-9]+\>)
```

This is what I expect that it should work but actually it does not:

```
(<\s*[0-9]+\>)(.*?[^<]*?)(<\s*[0-9]+\>)\1
```

I tried with this editor but the backreference does not work as I expect. Why does the backreference to the first capture group not work? The solution should work in C++.

http://regexr.com/3ek1a

Comment: Show the code where you are using it. BTW, you consume the tag with the second `<\s*[0-9]+>`. Just try `(<\s*[0-9]+>)([^<]*)\1`, see [this demo](http://regexr.com/3ek1j).

Comment: C and C++ are *not* the same language.

Comment: Are you working in C or C++?  The answers are vastly, hugely, completely different.  C++ has regular expressions in the standard library; C does not.  If you're programming in C, the question becomes "which regex package are you using".  If you're programming in C++, that's really a non-issue; you're using `<regex>` unless there are peculiar requirements to the contrary (which should be stated clearly in the question if they exist).

Comment: I have adjusted the question. I need it for C++. There is no code yet as I wanted to check if my idea is working before implementing it!

Comment: Why do you use `\s*`? Can there be `< 1> text < 1>`? If yes, can there be `<1> text < 1 >`?

Comment: Actually s* seems to be wrong at this place. I believe that is left over from trying to support line breaks. I would have accepted your solution as answer but unfortunately your answer is a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<\s*(\d+)\s*>((.|\n)*?)<\s*\1\s*>
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kdhygm/1)

1. 1st Capturing Group  (\d+)
2. \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
3. +Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times(greedy)
4. (.|\n)*? . matches any character (except for line terminators), and \n
   matches line terminators
5. ? makes it lazy (lazy)
6. \1 backreference to the first capturing group

C++14 Code Sample:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string regx = R"(<\s*(\d+)\s*>((.|\n)*?)<\s*\1\s*>)";
    string input = "<1>test1<1><2>Tes\nt2<2>sfsaf<3><4>test4<4>";
    smatch matches;
        while (regex_search(input, matches, regex(regx)))
        {
            cout<<matches[2]<<endl;
            input = matches.suffix().str();
        }
    return 0;
}
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/AvuWPi)

Comment: This solution does not recognize linebreaks as mentioned in the question.

Comment: updated the answer... i didn't notice the \n at the first place ;) try now